# setValue of an empty FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a method, that returns a FormGroup object.

```
public static createFormGroup(...): FormGroup { ... returns formGroupWithControls}
```

Generally, I already have a FormGroup within a FormArray. I want to create new FormGroups and replace the value of the FormGroup (in the FormArray) with the value of the new created FormGroup (from the above method)

```
this.removeControls(); // removes all Controls in "formGroupReferencedInFormArray"
this.formGroupReferencedInFormArray.patchValue(FormGroupFactory.createFormGroup(...));
```

After this call the FormGroup "formGroupReferencedInFormArray" is empty... But I would like to have the value of the returned FormGroup within "formGroupReferencedInFormArray".

Comment: I think you could use `formArray.setControl(index, youFormGroupInstance)`

Comment: Thank you very much! This works for me! If you answer this question, I will accept that answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `formArray.setControl(index, youFormGroupInstance)`.

[*Source code*](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1792)